# How do I replace an element in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not really sure how to properly word my question but I will try my best. 
I'm working on a class project and one part is using lists.

So first off I set random values in a list. `a = [1,1,1,0,0,0,0]`

To make this clearer let's say I'm making a program to manage the seating arrangement in a cinema. 1 is for taken and 0 is for vacant. So this means that there are only 4 vacant seats remaining. A customer uses the program and the program chooses the seat for the customer, so the first zero is chosen and now there are only three vacant seats left. Another customer uses the program and the same thing happens until all the seats are taken which will then print a statement that says "All seats are taken"

How do I pull this off?

I hope I was able to word this question properly

Thanks in advance!

Here's what I have tried. (and absolutely failed lol):

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in a:
    if i ==0:
        a[i] = 1
```

Edit:

```
while True:
    seats = [1,1,1,0,0,0]
    for i, seat in enumerate(seats):
        if seat == 0:
            seats[i] = 1
            print("Your seat is at", i)
            break  
    else:  
        print("No more seats!")
    user = int(input("Press 1 to reserve another seat, 2 to quit the program"))
    if user == 2:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing from the type of question, some of this might be new to you. However, I believe it's always nice to see different ways to do things, and you can always look stuff up and learn something new!

You'll need to check the list for zeros, and if one is found, switch it with a 1. Importantly, you should then stop (`break`) looking, as you don't want to fill all seats at once.

Something like this is a possible way to write that up (again, many ways to do this, this is just one). You would still need to repeat this process however many times you want to seat someone.

```
for i, seat in enumerate(seats):
    if seat == 0:
        seats[i] = 1
        print("Your seat is at", i)
        break  # Stop looking for seats.
else:  # If no break happened. 
    print("No more seats!")
```

Comment: Yes I'm totally new to python, but I understand most of your codes except for this line here. Can you please explain this line to me?

`for i, seat in enumerate(seats):`

Comment: @BaoHsu Sure. `enumerate` is a way to give you both the elements in the list, _and_ the index to it at the same time. In the snippet above, `i` is the index and `seat` is the element. That means that `seats[i] == seat`. An example, try to run this code:
`for i, elem in enumerate(['hello', 'world']):
    print(i, elem)`

Comment: Okay I get it now! But what if I wanted to loop this code? Like if I run this code it will assign a seat to the user and the 0 in the list will turn into a one and so on until all the zeroes in the list becomes a one and the user gets notified that all seats are taken. I tried doing it using `while True:` but it just kept on assigning me to the same seat over and over.

Comment: Edit: I placed the code in the original post to make it more readable

Comment: @BaoHsu It's because you define your `seats` list _inside_ the loop. That means it gets reset every time, and so the same seat is assigned each time as well. Just move that line outside the `while` loop and I think you're there.

Answer (score 1):

`a[a.index(0)] = 1` will replace the first zero found with a one, and throw an exception if there are no more zeros.  You can catch the exception:

```
try:
    a[a.index(0)] = 1
except ValueError:
    print('no more seats')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet will set the first element to `1` if it is `0`. You need a way to find the index of the first element that is 0 and just set that to `1`.

Try the [index](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/list_index.htm) function to get the index for one element and use that...or just save the total and currently occupied seat counts as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you comparing i with 0, when you should be checking the array content:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i, val in enumerate(a):
    if val == 0:
        a[i] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           a =[1,1,1,0,0,0]
           for x in sorted(a):
             if len(a) == sum(a):
               print('seats are full ')
             else:   
                 a[x].pop
                 a.append(1)
                 print ('your  seat is at a[x]')
```

Comment: need explation about your answer so other user can understand

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have given two fixes for your problem, using both `for` and `while` loops. Personally, I believe the while loop is much more preferable in this scenario, to avoid using the `break` command.

```
def original_main():
    a = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for i in a:
        # i here will be equal to the values in the list, what happens here is that the value is being copied to a new paramater.
        if i == 0:
            a[i] = 1

    print('original_main:', a)


def fixed_main():
    a = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    for index, value in enumerate(a):
        # What happens here is that enumerate takes both the index and value of the element and uses them.
        # You check whether the value of the seat is 0, AKA free.
        if value == 0:
            # You update the location of the same element/ seat to being occupied.
            a[index] = 1
            # To stop the loop, often preferable not to need to use breaks.
            break
    print('fixed_main:', a)


def alternative_main():
    a = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    index = 0
    # Cycle through the list until reaching the end of the list or the seat is free.
    while index < len(a) and a[index] != 0:
        index += 1

    # Check whether there were any empty seats as if there weren't index will be higher or equal to the amount of seats.
    # Thechnically it can only be equal due to the while condition but it is a better practice to cover all scenarios.
    if index >= len(a):
        print('No empty seats.')
    else:
        a[index] = 1

    print('alternative_main:', a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    original_main()
    print()
    fixed_main()
    alternative_main()
```

Printed result:

```
original_main: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

fixed_main: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
alternative_main: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```